# How do I generate the private key needed to restore the encrypted backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2019, encryption, certificate

I'm simulating the situation where I take a backup from instance **A** and restore it on instance **B**. I followed the doc to [Backup to Disk with Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-an-encrypted-backup?view=sql-server-ver15#backup-to-disk-with-encryption). Since I'm using only my desktop to simulate the whole process, after taking the backup of the database I took a backup of the certificate that was used as follows:

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE MyTestDBBackupEncryptCert
TO FILE = N'C:\Databases\MyTestDBBackupEncryptCert.cert';
```

Then I dropped the `MyTestDBBackupEncryptCert` certificate and the database from my instance to simulate it is now instance **B**. I restored the certificate using the command from the [Creating a certificate from a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-creating-a-certificate-from-a-file) doc with a slight modification where I commented the lines related to the `PRIVATE KEY` and `DECRYPTION` options since the certificate was encrypted by the `MASTER KEY` (well, that's what I understood from the first link):

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE MyTestDBBackupEncryptCert   
    FROM FILE = N'C:\Databases\MyTestDBBackupEncryptCert.cert'   
    --WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'c:\Shipping\Certs\Shipping11.pvk',   
    --DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'sldkflk34et6gs%53#v00');  
GO
```

The certificate was created, but when I try to restore the database, I get this error:

> Msg 15507, Level 16, State 30, Line 33 
> A key required by this
> operation appears to be corrupted. 
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line
> 33 
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

The documentation doesn't say how to get the private key needed to properly restore the certificate. How do I get it from SQL Server?

Comment: Take a look at the [`BACKUP CERTIFICATE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), including the `WITH PRIVATE KEY` clause

Comment: ¬¬ I can't believe I missed that. The syntax says `TO FILE = 'path_to_file'` for the certificate backup, but only `FILE = 'path_to_private_key_file'` for the private key instead of `TO FILE = 'path_to_private_key_file'`. That made me think I should use it to refer to a file that already existed. 3 days gone.... Thanks a lot, @AMtwo. You can write the answer to be accepted if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private key is used as part of the `BACKUP CERTIFICATE` syntax. Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the syntax is:

```sql
BACKUP CERTIFICATE certname TO FILE = 'path_to_file'  
    [ WITH PRIVATE KEY   
      (   
        FILE = 'path_to_private_key_file' ,  
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'encryption_password'   
        [ , DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'decryption_password' ]   
      )   
    ]
```

As you discovered, A "simple" `BACKUP CERTICIATE` without a private key isn't sufficient to be restored for use to decrypt. To make your certificate backup useful for restoring encrypted backups you **must** backup the certificate `WITH PRIVATE KEY`.

Once you know this, it's easier to remember, because you need *the key* to unlock the encryption---but the fact that the "simple" certificate backup is possible without any warning does represent a big pitfall, and also demonstrates the importance of testing *your restore strategy*, particularly when encryption keys are involved.